# button text stacking vs keeping inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with the text "Learn More"

The buttons text is stacking on top of each other vs flowing in line.

My html code for the button is as follows:

I am including the entire row that the button is in first the code specific to the button in question is marked. These two code snippts are all in one bootstrap row

```
<div class="row"> <!--bottom row-->
     <div class="leftbutton col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
       <a id="helpbutton" href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Help"><button>Help</button></a>
     </div>
```

Here is the code for the button in question below..

```
     <div class="rightbutton col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
       <button>Learn More</button>
     </div>

   </div> <!--end bottom row-->
```

my css for the button is as follows:

```
.rightbutton button{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1c94c4;
    padding-left: 40%;
    padding-right: 40%;
  }
```

what is going on? I was thinking the font, but that doesn't make any sense to me.

Another pair of eyes is appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to be manipulate the css you are facing, https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/ZXoLgz, is this what you are currently facing now?

Comment: thats correct that is my current situation. An answer has been provided to use `whitespace: no wrap` I am going to give that a try! Thank you for your help and for taking the time to do a code pen @Vi

Comment: ok let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: Will do enjoy your night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space:nowrap`

CSS:

```
.rightbutton button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c94c4;
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 40%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/2156/

The issue is because of the padding unit in the percentage which varies according to the screen size while the text size remains fixed.

Comment: @amazingCarrotSoup Thank you. You may mark it as an answer to close this post.